# Performing a Do Until with an If statement until a certain value is reached

Tags: vba, excel

I am dealing with a large data sheet. I need code to subtract from a specific cell until the value is greater then a certain number. if that number isn't achieved I want it to go to 0.

For example if `A3-A2 > Q5 then E3= A3-A2 if < Q5 do A3-A1`. If this doesn't work `E2=0`. I need this to be continuous down the whole A column. So far, my code is as follows:

```
Do Until Range("A3").Offset(1, 0) - Range("A2") > Range("Q5")
  If Range("A3").Offset(1, 0) - Range("A2") > Range("Q5") Then
    Range("E3").End(xlDown) = Range("A3").Offset(1, 0) - Range("A2")
  Else: Range("E3").End(xlDown) = 0
  End If
Loop
```

It doesn't seem to like the way I enter it. and I don't think the offset is right.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using the `.Offset`?

Comment: I dont know how to make it go down by increments of one. I tried .end(xldown) also and that didnt seem to work. I dont normally code so this is very new to me

Comment: Could you mock up some data and expected output?  It is hard to follow what you want.

Comment: I just added a link for mock data. I hope it helps i am having trouble explaining it.

Comment: Do your problems have anything to do with the fact that there's nothing in `Q5`? The only value I see in column Q is in `Q 4`...

Comment: No the picture was just rough its supposed to be in Q5 not Q4.

Answer (score -2):

It's a bad practice to use `While`, `Until`, `While...WEnd`.
Use unconditional `Do...Loop` with full-featured condition check code and `Exit Do`, which you can locate in any place of cycle, but not in beginning or end of it only.

---

-1? OK :)

> **MS F1:** Tip   The Do...Loop statement provides a more structured and flexible way to perform looping.

This "services" are for the lazy only. My denie of `While` and `Until` is the direct consequence of this statement exactly to **achieve "structured and flexible"**, about which topick starter is asked for.

Comment: Downvoted because this is not only unsupported opinion but promotes poor logic discipline (why use `Exit` if a well defined stopping condition exists). Also does not address the issue the OP has.