# VBA subscript out of range error - do while multiple conditions

Tags: vba

I am getting error message "subscript out of range" locating at the do while multiple conditions line. can someone please help and see why my conditions are wrong? Many thanks!

```
Do While ((fixeddaysdiff_input(i + C, 2) = fixeddaysdiff_input(i + C - 1, 2)) _
     And (fixeddaysdiff_input(i + C, 1) = fixeddaysdiff_input(i + C - 1, 1))) _
     Or ((fixeddaysdiff_input(i + C, 2) = fixeddaysdiff_input(i + C + 1, 2)) _
     And (fixeddaysdiff_input(i + C, 1) = fixeddaysdiff_input(i + C + 1, 1)))

     C = C + 1
     accumulatedvalue(i + C, 1) = accumulatedvalue(i + C - 1, 1) + fixeddaysdiff_output(i, 4) - fixeddaysdiff_output(i, 22)
Loop
```

Comment: what is `fixeddaysdiff_input` ? `Range`, `Array`, can you please give us more data here

Comment: In addition to @ShaiRado's questions, how are you defining "I" and "C"?

Answer (score -2):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49456115/6698332), please.
Yesterday only I wrote and got -1 :)))

Re: "subscript out of range"
1. Carefully read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264519%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).
2. Check the behavoir of secret variable `i`
.

Comment: Downvoted because this does not provide any meaningful answer to the OP's problem. The referenced article has no relevance to the question at hand (does anyone use VS 6?). `i` is not a secret variable - it is there in the code in plain view!

Comment: @AJD :) The answer is in the F1. It need only to open the book. It is the main OP's problem :) The article has rekevance to described error. _"does anyone use VS 6"_ - look on tags VB6, VBA & all VBA-office_clones :))) `i` - _"in the code in plain view"_ is only a symbol. It's not assigned here, it's passed from somewhere. What its value? However it act in pointing to certain arrays element.

Comment: "Carefully read this." - what happens when this disappears? There should be enough relevant information visible in the answer to be helpful to the OP and to others.

Comment: @QHarr Who are you? Was my advice for you? Or you (having 6K+ of rep) have the same problem as OP? If so - do RTFM too. However, I had posted the answer. You has posted nothing. Please, post disproof of me together with your own view, instead of to behave like the petty angry troll, who has many of time but nothing to fill it.